# Animation code doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this demo:

[jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/WFVby/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {        
    $(".footer-list li").mouseover(function() {
         $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: "#d31d4a" }, 1500);
        // $(this).css("background-color", "#d31d4a");
    });
});
```

Animation code doesn't work and I have no idea why!!

When I use `.css`, it works without any problems.

Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Comment: Post relevant code, not just a link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery doesn't animate colors out-of-the-box, so you need a color animation plugin, like [this one](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/jquery.animate-colors-min.js). Just include it and everything should work.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WFVby/2/

Answer (score 1):

As the others said, jQuery's `.animate()` doesn't do colour animations by default. Another option to make it work is to include [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/), which (amongst other things) "upgrades" the default `.animate()` method (as demonstrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/WFVby/3/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a "jquery.Color" plugin installed:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color